# what does this notation in hive script(hivequery.hql) file mean "use ${word:word}"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hadoop, hive

The script (hivequery.hql:) looks like this:

```
Use ${platformType:platformName};

select * from hivetablename;
```

And this script is being called in a bash script as

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
hive -f hivequery.hql
```

Comment: I think it is done to select the database , on lines of 
    use database_name 
and the ${platformType:platformName} , It is construct of form ${parameter :offset } . Offset here gives the starting point . 
For ex - parameter='dbsybase' , then ${parameter:3} will equate to 'sybase'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within an hql file, the `use` command sets the default database.  See [Use Database](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/AlterDatabase).

The `${platformType:platformName}` is Hive's variable notation where `platformType` is the namespace and `platformName` is the variable name. This is explained in the [Using Variables](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VariableSubstitution#LanguageManualVariableSubstitution-UsingVariables) section of the Language Manual.

If you want to see what value a specific variable has, you can just use `set` like:

```
set platformType:platformName;
```

and it will print out the value.  You can also run `set;` to get a full listing of known variables in all namespaces.

Comment: Thank you for the links. It helped clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The more correct way to write the construct `${word:word}` would be to write `${parameter:offset}` . It cause parameter expansion,  it expands to the portion of the value of parameter  starting at the character (counting from 0 ) determined by expanding offset to the end of the parameter . It has one more variant as `${parameter:offset:length }` - Expands to the portion of the value of parameter  starting at the character (counting from 0 ) determined by expanding offset  as an arithmetic expression and consisting of the number of characters determined by the arithmetic expression defined by length.

So I think basically the in your case , it is meant to get the name of the database from platformType.

For more details on this look into the 
Look for **Parameter Expansion** in the bash man page.